# Counting the number of times an observation exists in a dataset using R? (with multiple criteria)

Tags: r

So I have this dataset of about 2,800 observations. The headers look a little something like this:

```
ItemName ItemNumber PromotedDate
ItemA    14321      12/31/2018
ItemB    14335      11/18/2018
ItemC    14542      10/05/2018
```

I want to be able to add a new column to this dataset, `Number.Times.Promoted.Last.3.Months`, that would count how many times each item exists in the dataset over the last three months of the `PromotedDate` variable.

I've tried creating some code (below) but it returns 0 for every row. When I just try it with the item number, I get the number of observations in the entire dataset.

```
df$Number.Times.Promoted.Last.Three.Months <- sum(df$ItemNumber == df$ItemNumber & 
                                                    df$PromotedDate < df$PromotedDate & 
                                                    df$PromotedDate > (as.Date(df$PromotedDate - 100)),
                                                  na.rm=TRUE)))
```

I'd love for the code to return the actual number of times each item in the dataset was promoted over the last 3 months since the `PromotedDate` variable, and for that to be attached to each row of the data (`df`). Would love some help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Please format your question and provide the data in an easy-to-paste manner and what the expected result would be. Think of some edge cases you would like to cover as well.

Comment: 1) In the first  rows you have items with different names but equal numbers. Is this an error? If not, how do you tell the items apart? 2) What is *to promote an item*?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to upload files here. If there is, let me know! But otherwise, I've created an example file in Excel of what I mean: https://ufile.io/zwg7p9n1

The item numbers being the same was a typo, so thanks for catching that. And let me give some quick context. So the dataset details every item that was promoted over the past year at a company. The "PromotedDate" variable is when it was promoted. Many items will be listed multiple times (since they were promoted during multiple months). When an item is promoted, it's logged in this dataset I'm working with.

Comment: To answer Roman's question too, the ultimate goal here is to count--for every row, how many times the item was promoted over the last three months for each respective row. I'm trying to create a machine learning algorithm, and I think that knowing how many times each item was previously promoted when it was ran would be very useful for the model.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** In the file linked to there is a typo, the first `ItemB` starts with a lower case `i`. The code below works even if this is not corrected.

I find the following solution a bit too complicated but it does what the question asks for.

```
library(lubridate)

fun <- function(x){
  ifelse(month(x) == 12 & day(x) == 31,
         x - days(31 + 30 + 31),
         x - months(3)
  )
}

df <- readxl::read_xlsx("example_20190519.xlsx")
df$PromotedDate <- as.Date(df$PromotedDate)

sp <- split(df, tolower(df$ItemName))
res <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  tmp <- as.Date(fun(DF$PromotedDate), origin = "1970-01-01")
  sapply(seq_len(nrow(DF)), function(i){
    sum(DF$PromotedDate[i] > DF$PromotedDate & DF$PromotedDate > tmp[i])
  })
})

df$New.3.Months <- NA
for(nm in names(res)) {
  df$New.3.Months[tolower(df$ItemName) == nm] <- res[[nm]]
}
```

Now test to see if the result is the same as in the example `.xlsx` file.

```
all.equal(df$Times.Promoted.Last.3.Months, df$New.3.Months)
#[1] TRUE
```

And final cleanup.

```
rm(sp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an arguably simpler solution that relies on `dplyr` and `fuzzyjoin`.

First I define a day 90 days earlier**, and then join the list with itself, pulling in each Item match with a promotion date that is both "since 90 days before" and "up to current date." The number of rows for each Item-Date is the number of promotions within 90 days. By subtracting the row representing itself, we get the number of prior promotions.

** "90 days earlier" is simpler than "3mo earlier," which varies in length and is arguable for some dates: what's 3 months before May 30?

Prep

```
library(dplyr); library(fuzzyjoin); library(lubridate)
df <- readxl::read_excel(
  "~/Downloads/example_20190519.xlsx", 
  col_types = c("text", "numeric", "date", "numeric"))
df_clean <- df %>% select(-Times.Promoted.Last.3.Months)
```

Solution

```
df_clean %>%
  mutate(PromotedDate_less90 = PromotedDate - days(90)) %>%

  # Pull in all matches (including current row) with matching Item and Promoted Date 
  #   that is between Promoted Date and 90 days prior.
  fuzzy_left_join(df_clean, 
                  by = c("ItemName" = "ItemName",
                         "ItemNumber" = "ItemNumber",
                         "PromotedDate_less90" = "PromotedDate",
                         "PromotedDate" = "PromotedDate"),
                  match_fun = list(`==`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`)
                  ) %>%
  group_by(ItemName     = ItemName.x, 
           ItemNumber   = ItemNumber.x, 
           PromotedDate = PromotedDate.x) %>%
  summarize(promotions_in_prior_90d = n() - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output (in different order, but matching goal)

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   ItemName ItemNumber PromotedDate        promotions_in_prior_90d
   <chr>         <dbl> <dttm>                                <dbl>
 1 ItemA         10021 2018-09-19 00:00:00                       0
 2 ItemA         10021 2018-10-15 00:00:00                       1
 3 ItemA         10021 2018-11-30 00:00:00                       2
 4 ItemA         10021 2018-12-31 00:00:00                       2
 5 itemB         10024 2018-12-15 00:00:00                       0
 6 ItemB         10024 2018-04-02 00:00:00                       0
 7 ItemB         10024 2018-06-05 00:00:00                       1
 8 ItemB         10024 2018-12-01 00:00:00                       0
 9 ItemC         19542 2018-07-20 00:00:00                       0
10 ItemC         19542 2018-11-17 00:00:00                       0
11 ItemC         19542 2018-12-01 00:00:00                       1
12 ItemC         19542 2018-12-14 00:00:00                       2
```